# How can I get my hedgehog to be more interactive?

Tags: behavior, hedgehog

I've had my hedgehog for close to a year now and she's very sweet most of the time, but she doesn't really like to be very interactive. She will get up during the night and run on her wheel, eat, and drink but won't be very active any other parts of the day. I'll get her out and she almost always hides her head in my arms and goes to sleep. I've tried to get her used to my scent by putting a shirt I wore all day in her cage, but to no avail. I want to play with her more, but she doesn't really like to do anything except at night. What can I do?

Comment: I have a similar situation. I only handle him at night. Even then, whenever I'm near, he rolls into a tight ball. He won't eat if he can see me. I've had him for over a month and I don't feel like there has been any bonding between us.

Answer (score 4):

Hedgehogs are nocturnal animals, trying to make her play during the day would be like someone waking you up at 2:30 am to play a football match. You are disturbing her natural cycles, which has all kinds of adverse effects on her health.

Anecdotically, I've seen a nocturnal animal section in a zoo where they had an inverted day/night cycle by having the building in darkness during the day, and fully illuminated during the night; but I don't think you can get that one right at home.